# How to forward SMS without interaction in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sms

I'm trying to forward an SMS from the app as I received the SMS. Here is my previous code where I toast the message body on the app as it received. Now I want to forward this message body to a particular number already added in the code.

```
mymessage() {
SmsReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();
receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) => Fluttertoast.showToast(
    msg: msg.body,
    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
    timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    textColor: Colors.white,
    fontSize: 16.0
    )
);
```

}

Now the main purpose is to Toast the body of message as well as forward it to a number

Comment: I don't  understand what you want?

Comment: As you see in the above code, I get body of an sms and toast it. Now I want to forward that body of sms to a number instead of toasting it

Comment: you want send sms to received number?

Comment: No, I want to forward that received sms to a new number that will hard coded in the code

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms)

Make sure to Install and Import the Package.

```
import 'package:flutter_sms/flutter_sms.dart';
```

Create a function for sending messages.

```
void _sendSMS(String message, List<String> recipents) async {
 String _result = await sendSMS(message: message, recipients: recipents)
        .catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
print(_result);
}
```

You can quickly send the message with this function.

```
String message = "This is a test message!";
List<String> recipents = ["1234567890", "5556787676"];

_sendSMS(message, recipents);
```

***UPDATE***

If I understand right you can do :

```
mymessage() {
SmsReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();
receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg){ 
_sendSMS(message, [msg.body]); // guess msg.body is your number
 
Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: msg.body,
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
        )
    );
}
```

Or instead of `Fluttertoast.showToast(` you can rebuild your widget with `setState()` or other state managements like provider, Getx or bloc.

Comment: it is working but how can I automate this process. So that this message will automatically forward to a number without going to built in sms screen

Comment: So can I simple replace msg.body with a number?

Comment: Yes, If `msg.body` is number @ZuHaib